# Like/Upvote: Separate table or as an entity in Comments table

Tags: mysql

Which is more efficient to use in the long run in storing "likes" in a database?
1. A separate "likes" table where comment_id is a foreign key and likes appended to their respective comments on the frontend.
or
2. For "likes" to be on of the columns in the Comments table and outputted along with Comments on fetch.

Comment: The best option for long run is a table for likes and another one for comments, so I guess option 1 is better

Comment: Alright thanks. I was thinking the table in scenario 1 would break down due to a lot of ones stored ad infinitum